# How can I get statistics on the number or percentage of users that have completed a level in my SpriteKit game?

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit, swift3

I need to be able to track user related statistics, especially related to level completion within my SpriteKit game. I believe Apple doesn't have any API's for tracking these stats (I stand to be corrected). How can I track these stats in a simple way?

Comment: Search for iOS app analytics.  There are a number of providers, including Google

Answer (score 1):

If levels are relevant in size, I'd rather add an optimization that collaterally gives you the data you need: [on-demand resources](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/)

You'll have smaller binaries at first download time, your users will download new levels as they complete them, and you'll know it.